# Using the top left corner of `TableForm->TableHeadings`

Tags: headers-footers, output-formatting

In the following `Table`

```
TableForm[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"x<=0", "x>0"}, {"y<=0", "y>0"}}]
```

I want to use the empty space in the top left corner to add `"TITLE"` to explain what the values in the table denote. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can post process the output of `Tableform` :

```
exp00 = TableForm[{{1 + 1, 0}, {0, 1}}, TableHeadings -> {{"x<=0", "x>0"}, {"y<=0", "y>0"}}]
exp01 = ToBoxes[exp00] /. (x : GridBox[___]) :>  MapAt["\"some text\"" &, x, {1, 1, 1}];
exp02 = RawBoxes[exp01]
```

[image]
[image]

Sometimes the insertion point (here : `{1,1,1}`) is a little tricky  to find because the target is embedded in some wrapper boxes (such as `TagBox`, `InterpretationBox` ...)

Answer (score 2):

```
Grid[Prepend[Join[List /@ {"x<=0", "x>0"}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, 2], 
  {"Title", "y<=0", "y>0"}], 
 Dividers -> {{False, 2 -> True}, {False, 2 -> True}}]
```

[image]

**Update:** A variation on andre2314's approach to post-process:

```
addTitle[t_] := RawBoxes@Replace[ToBoxes@#, "\[Null]" :> t /. Style -> StyleBox, All] &


addTitle[Style["Title", 24, Red, Bold]]@
 TableForm[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, TableHeadings -> {{"x<=0", "x>0"}, {"y<=0", "y>0"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Marked as answered. But there's no way to do this with a table, then? So I can't do it with evaluated values?

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward, I don't know of any way to do it using `TableForm`.

Comment: OK. Case closed. Appreciated @kglr

Comment: Many apologies @kglr, but I have to accept the answer below as more complete. I appreciate both of your inputs, of course.